# How to get coefficients from a logistic regression in AutoML Databricks

Tags: model, databricks, logistic-regression, coefficients, automl

Hope everyone enjoys this day ;)

It's the first time that I have used AutoML in Databricks. So sorry if my question is easy (and sorry for my poor English, I'm French) :P

One of my best models in AutoML is a logistic regression and I wanted to have the coefficient of each variable.
I only can find the "Feature importance" when I put the 'shap_enabled' to 'True'.
But this doesn't help me.
I want to be able to 'write manually' my mode.
For example, if my model is: temperature = 0.12 + 2.3percent_of_CO2 + 1.2percent_of_humidity).
I would like to collect, the 0.12, 2.3 (percent_of_CO2), 1.2 (percent_of_humidity).

Thank you in advance for your help!
Best regards

Alison

I try to see on other forums but it seems that there is no answer.
and I tried to adapt a code that I use for the decision tree in pysparks but it didn't succeed either.

````
Feature_importance = sorted((attr["idx"], attr["name"]) for attr in (chain(*pipdata.schema["features"].metadata["ml_attr"]["attrs"].values())))
    Final_list = [(name, idx, bestmodel.featureImportances[idx]) for idx, name in Feature_importance]
    Features_Importances = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame(Final_list, columns =['Features_names', 'Features_Index','Features_Importance'])).coalesce(1)
    display(Features_Importances)
    Features_Importances_PD = Features_Importances.toPandas()
    Features_Importances_PD['Features_Index'] = "feature "+Features_Importances_PD['Features_Index'].astype(str)
    Dictionnaire = pd.Series(Features_Importances_PD.Features_names.values,index = Features_Importances_PD.Features_Index).to_dict()
    interpretation_model = bestmodel.toDebugString
    for word, initial in Dictionnaire.items():
      interpretation_model = interpretation_model.replace(word.lower()+" ", initial)```
````